# Error trying to display image from external API (Unexpected token � in JSON)

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to display an image from an external api. But I only get the error

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0"

I guess the question mark means that it's something unidentified...

Anyhow I followed the documentation for the api on how to display images. To get an image from the register i'm using endpoint Article File Connections to get the FileId which I use in the Archive endpoint to get the image.

Here is the documentation for the both endpoints:

- https://developer.fortnox.se/documentation/resources/article-file-connections/
- https://developer.fortnox.se/documentation/resources/archive/

When I try the endpoints with the `itemId` and the `FileId` in postman it works and shows the image but not in my code. So there is something I'm doing wrong in the code. But what is it?

I think it's a problem in my `SingleProductImage` page, can someone please help?

I'm using React hooks to fetch the api, here is my code:

```
export const SingleProductImage = (props) => {
  const [articleImg, setArticleImg] = useState('')
  console.log(articleImg) // when I console this nothing shows
  console.log(props.fileid) // when I console this the fileid shows

  useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.fortnox.se/3/archive/${props.fileid}', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Access-Token': accessToken,
          'Client-Secret': clientSecret
        }
      })
    
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setArticleImg(data)
      console.log(data)
    })
  }, [articleImg])

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={articleImg} alt="product" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

SingleProductImage page

```
export const SingleProductPage = () => {
  const { itemId } = useParams()
  const [article, setArticle] = useState([])
  const [articleImg, setArticleImg] = useState('')
  const [fileId, setFileId] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.fortnox.se/3/articles/${itemId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Access-Token': accessToken,
        'Client-Secret': clientSecret
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        setArticle(data.Article)
        console.log(data)
      })
  }, [itemId])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.fortnox.se/3/articlefileconnections/?articlenumber=${itemId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Access-Token': accessToken,
        'Client-Secret': clientSecret
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setFileId(data.ArticleFileConnections[0].FileId)
        console.log(data.ArticleFileConnections[0].FileId)
      })
  }, [itemId])

  return (
        <div>
          <SingleProductImage fileid={fileId} />
        </div>
)
```

Comment: add a `console.log(res)` in this part of your code `.then((res) => res.json())` instead of doing the .json and have a look at what the response is. Didn't go through the documentation of your api provider but it probably isn't what you expect, i.e just the url

Comment: I added the console.log(res) as you suggested and I think I get the response I was expecting, it is the url that with the correct fileId as I tried in postman.

Comment: It looks like this: Response {type: "cors", url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.fo…se/3/archive/8c05c536-c110-402d-82da-60f25f6b0e1c", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Comment: As you see you are not getting just the URL but an object with other info. Then you need to take res.url and not the whole res, as your url is stored under the 'url' key, and it should solve your error.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the `.json()` on the whole object that the api is returning. Instead take only the url and your error should go away

```
... 
.then((res)=> setArticleImg(res.url))
.catch((err)=> console.log(err))
```

Comment: Thank you!! This made my error go away. Yay. But now I get another error on GET with a status of 400 Bad request. I think it is because I prefixed "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" to my URL. But I don't now have to solve the blocked by CORS error without it.